# helper declaration prevents external storage

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

We are tying to use Secondary EXTERNAL storage on the emulator and this works great. The user can select external or internal storage. Android build 26.0.2 
YES manifest has permissions. When this line of code is included in the launcher Activity the storage is defaulted to INTERNAL helper = new DBHelper(this);
helper is declared static. The big benefit of using that line of code is that when the app is stopped or when we close the app with Clear All in the emulator the bound data in the ArrayList that is backed by a RecyclerAdapter persists. So not using the helper declaration except when needed in the Activity creates the need to reload data from the database and populate the ArrayList. This is where we have become lost. We have tried to call the method in the DBhelper that loads the ArrayList. To no avail code below is in the ListActivity. The app always returns to the MainActivity after being closed. So the question is where and how do I place the code to repopulate the ArrayList from the database ?

```
    }// End of onCreate Bundle

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    helper = new DBHelper(this);
    dbList = new ArrayList<>();
    dbList = helper.getDataFromDB();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to test this and discovered that you do not need the line of code 
 helper = new DBHelper(this); The issue is somewhere in your MainActivity your code is making a trip over to the DBHelper BEFORE the variable THE_PATH is set where ever you are defining that variable. In my testing I found you need to establish the contents of the variable THE_PATH that is being passed to DBHelper before that trip is made. While testing I changed the config.ini to excluded the SD CARD from the emulator and Android would just use internal storage.
So as of now my testing still did not permit the user to select storage type.
If the DB is beyond the storage capacity of internal memory than just set the default to EXTERNAL storage. As you know the data is not real secure on the SD CARD

Comment: What happens if no SD CARD is available after the data was previously saved to the SD CARD Will test the idea and accept answer

Comment: @James_Duh Android will default to INTERNAL storage or best design would be let the user know they had previously used EXTERNAL storage by storing that value somewhere in a txt file or a in the database